# Getting corresponding values in list box by clicking on specific value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am getting values in dropdown form my json and I am trying when I click on one value from dropdown then list box shud get populated. for example,
As below you can see my json file as now i m getting values in 1st dropdown as obs, hid I want.. say if i click on obs in list box i want to get brs1,crs1,drs1.

```
[{
  "name": "obs",
  "date": "1458834026000",
  "attr001": "brs1",
  "attr002": "crs1",
  "attr003": "drs1",
}, {
  "name": "hid",
  "date": "1458774000000",
  "attr001": "ffrs1",
  "attr002": "grrs1",
  "attr003": "mno1",
}, {
  "name": "qwe",
  "date": "1425744000000",
  "attr001": "klm1",
  "attr002": "wer1",
  "attr003": "iop1",
}, {
  "name": "rty",
  "date": "1458774000000",
  "attr001": "yrs1",
  "attr002": "qws1",
  "attr003": "prs1"
}]
```

My javascript file is like

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("data.json",function(obj) {
    var jsObject = $.parseJSON(obj);
        var usedNames = [];
        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
            if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
                $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                usedNames.push(value.name);
            }
    $('<option>', {
        text: 'Select your Option',
        value: '',
        selected: 'selected',
        disabled: 'disabled'
    }).appendTo('#dropdown1');

    $.each(jsObject, function (index, value) {
        $('<option>', {
            text: value['name'],
            value: index
        }).appendTo('#dropdown1');
    });

    $('<option>', {
        text: 'Select your List Option',
        value: '',
        selected: 'selected',
        disabled: 'disabled'
    }).appendTo('#listbox');


    $('#dropdown1').change(function () {
        $('#listbox').empty();

        $('<option>', {
            text: 'Select your List Option',
            value: '',
            selected: 'selected',
            disabled: 'disabled'
        }).appendTo('#listbox');

        var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
        $.each(jsObject, function (index, value) {
            if (value['name'] === selection) {
                $('<option>', {
                    text: value['attr001'],
                    value: 'attr001'
                }).appendTo('#listbox');
                $('<option>', {
                    text: value['attr002'],
                    value: 'attr002'
                }).appendTo('#listbox');
                $('<option>', {
                    text: value['attr003'],
                    value: 'attr003'
                }).appendTo('#listbox');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My html

```
<form name="myform" id="myForm">

    <select id="dropdown1"></select>
    <select id="listbox"></select>
    <br>
```

Please suggest something.. Thank you..

Comment: Your json data format is not correct. use " , " to saperate each value.

Comment: I have corrected my json now..

Comment: delete last " , "  after ( "attr003").

Comment: edited-.......have a look

Comment: in all of them... don't end comma-seperated lists with a comma

Comment: But my json is like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.getJSON("data.json",function(obj) {

var json_string = '[{"name":"obs","date":"1458834026000","attr001":"brs1","attr002":"crs1","attr003":"drs1"},{"name":"hid","date":"1458774000000","attr001":"ffrs1","attr002":"grrs1","attr003":"mno1"},{"name":"qwe","date":"1425744000000","attr001":"klm1","attr002":"wer1","attr003":"iop1"},{"name":"rty","date":"1458774000000","attr001":"yrs1","attr002":"qws1","attr003":"prs1"}]';
var jsObject = $.parseJSON(json_string);
// var jsObject = $.parseJSON(obj);  // Assuming yout obj contains the JSON Stirng

$('<option>', {
    text: 'Select your Option',
    value: '',
    selected: 'selected',
    disabled: 'disabled'
}).appendTo('#dropdown1');

$.each(jsObject, function (index, value) {
    $('<option>', {
        text: value['name'],
        value: index
    }).appendTo('#dropdown1');
});

$('<option>', {
    text: 'Select your List Option',
    value: '',
    selected: 'selected',
    disabled: 'disabled'
}).appendTo('#listbox');


$('#dropdown1').change(function () {
    $('#listbox').empty();

    $('<option>', {
        text: 'Select your List Option',
        value: '',
        selected: 'selected',
        disabled: 'disabled'
    }).appendTo('#listbox');

    var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
    $.each(jsObject, function (index, value) {
        if (value['name'] === selection) {
            $('<option>', {
                text: value['attr001'],
                value: 'attr001'
            }).appendTo('#listbox');
            $('<option>', {
                text: value['attr002'],
                value: 'attr002'
            }).appendTo('#listbox');
            $('<option>', {
                text: value['attr003'],
                value: 'attr003'
            }).appendTo('#listbox');
        }
    });
});
```

}

Here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ca1k73k/)

Comment: But I cannnot do like this  var json_string = '[{"name":"obs","date":"1458834026000","attr001":"brs1","attr002":"crs1","attr003":"drs1"...dont want to harcode list as this is just snippet of my json it is a long file

Comment: Reason ? What is stopping you ?

Comment: So only there is `var jsObject = $.parseJSON(obj);`

Comment: will you please have a look on my javascript what is the problem there...nothing coming in dropdown ..Will be grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use Id and class too when you are creating HTML

```
$("#dropdown1").append("<option id=" + value.name + " class="dropdown" value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
```

Than make a selector based on click on class like

```
$('.dropdown').on('change', function(){
    ele = $(this).attr('id');
})
```

Now you will have the name of selected element in ele than parse your json to get all attribute value for than name and populate listbox by that data

Comment: Please suggest me ..as I dont want to hardcode my data so I have changed my javascript file...please will You look at it once..I will be very thankful to you.